# Prevent converting null request parameter to zero in websphere jsf

Tags: jsf, configuration, websphere, el, faces-config

We use #{param.customId} in faces-config for getting parameter from request. In the glassfish2 it works fine, but under websphere 7.0 undefined BigDecimal null values change to zero (0). How to configure websphere to works as like as glassfish for these values?

Comment: looks like it knowing issue. I'm looking for universal solution like custom Converter or changing version on jsf. But I had trouble with implementing custom Converter for #{param.xxx} values.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it can help:

In tomcat7, values of empty double fields are changed to zero at update model phase. After i change default tomcat "el" implemantation with glassfish el impl, these values are read as null

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```